# Absolute value of a uniform convergent sequence

Tags: solution-verification, uniform-convergence

Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence that converges uniformly to some $f$.

I want to show that the sequence of absolute values $(|f_n|))$ converges uniformly to $|f|$.

Proof:

Uniform convergence of $f_n\to f$ is equivalent to convergence with regards to the supremum norm.

This means $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \|f_n-f\|_\infty =0$.

Now to show $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \||f_n|-|f|\|=0$, we use the reversed triangle inequality.

$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}  \||f_n|-|f|\|_\infty\leq \lim_{n\to\infty} \|f_n-f\|_\infty=0$.

Is this proof correct?
Thank you.